# Sorting an array in ascending order using pointers in C

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

I am writing a program that creates an array of random numbers from 1 to 100 and sorts them in ascending order. Below is working code that does this, but I need to modify it so that the "swap" function makes use of pointers. The call for the swap function should look like this: swap(???,???) where the two inputs are pointers. What is the best way to accomplish this?

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<math.h> 

    int main()
    {
       void fillArray(int sizeArray, int array[sizeArray]);
       void printArray(int sizeArray, int array[sizeArray]);
       void sortArray(int sizeArray, int array[sizeArray]);

       int sizeArray;

       printf("\nSize of the array? ");
       scanf("%d", &sizeArray);

       int array[sizeArray];

       fillArray(sizeArray,array);
       sortArray(sizeArray, array);
       printArray(sizeArray, array);
    }

    void fillArray(int sizeArray, int array[sizeArray])
    {
       int increment;

       for(increment=0; increment<sizeArray; increment++)
       {
          array[increment]=rand()%101;
       }
    }

    void sortArray(int sizeArray, int array[sizeArray])
    {
       void swap(int increment2, int increment, int array[]);
       int increment, increment2, temp;

       for (increment=0; increment < sizeArray ; increment++)
       {
          for (increment2=increment+1; increment2 < sizeArray; increment2++)
          {   
             swap(increment2, increment, array);
          }
       }
    }

    void swap(int increment2, int increment, int array[])
    {
       int temp;
       if (array[increment2] < array[increment])
             {
                temp=array[increment];
                array[increment]=array[increment2];
                array[increment2]=temp;
             }
    }

    void printArray(int sizeArray, int array[sizeArray])
    {
       int increment=0;

       printf("\nHere's the sorted array:\n");

       while(increment<21)
       {
          printf("\n    array[%d] is %d", increment, array[increment]);
          increment++;
       }
    }
```

The output should look like this:
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8wKW1.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using pointers to swap int array values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1670821/using-pointers-to-swap-int-array-values)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define your `swap` function as below:

```
void swap(int *increment2, int* increment)
```

Modify your for loop where you call the swap function:

```
for (increment=0; increment < sizeArray ; increment++)
{
      for (increment2=increment+1; increment2 < sizeArray; increment2++)
      {   
         swap(array[increment2], array[increment]);
      }
}
```

Then, modify your swap function:

```
void swap(int *increment2, int* increment)
{
       int temp;
       if (increment2 < increment)
       {
            temp= *increment2;
            *increment2=*increment;
            *increment2=temp;
       }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix your function call for the parameters to be with pointers.

```
void swap(int *increment2, int* increment)
```

Then in your swap function you need

You will need to deference the integer*.

```
Example
int n1;
int* x = 100
n1 = *x;
```

You may need to
deference in the future example

Your function accepts pointers

```
void swap(int *increment2, int* increment)
```

If you have integers or another data type to reference them, refer to their address, you can perform & for referencing.

```
int i = 5;
int* x;
x = &i;
```

x is now an integer pointer to the address of i.

Answer (score 0):

Your calling code needs to pass the address of the integers to compare and swap. Either of the following forms is acceptable, and they are equivalent.

```
swap(array+increment2, array+increment);
swap(&array[increment2], &array[increment]);
```

The first form takes the address of the first element (`array`) and adds the index (`increment2`) to get the address of the correct element.

The second version is more straightforward, perhaps. It uses the `&` address-of operator to take the address of `array[increment2]`, which is the desired integer.

Your `swap` function need to be defined as follows:

```
void swap(int** p2, int** p1)
{
    int temp;
    if (*p2 < *p1)
    {
        temp=*p1;
        *p1=*p2;
        *p2=temp;
    }
}
```

Note how the pointers are *dereferenced* with the `*` operator to get the integer values for comparison (and storage in `temp`).

Comment: If you're happy with the answer, please "accept" so that it can be closed.